# Laravel Middleware Route Group Problems

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, middleware

I'm using: Laravel Framework version 5.1.24 (LTS), and I am having great difficulty with implementing a Middleware route group.

Here is what I have in my `routes.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('api/users', 'UserController@getUsers');
    Route::get('api/user/{id}', 'UserController@viewUser');
    Route::post('api/user', 'UserController@addUser');
    Route::put('api/user/{id}', 'UserController@updateUser');
    Route::delete('api/user/{id}', 'UserController@deleteUser');
});
```

I've also added this to the `$routeMiddleware` array within `Kernel.php`:

```
'api' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthenticate::class,
```

I have the `ApiAuthtenticate` Middleware set to run before continuing, so I'm expecting to see the error handling I have in there, but I am not. What I do get is the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception thrown.

The strange thing is if I remove the Middleware route group, and add the `ApiAuthenticate` class to the `$middleware` array within `Kernel.php`, it behaves exactly as it should (throws my Exceptions). However, I want to use the Middleware on a specified group of routes, not on the entire global scope.

Can someone please help?

Here is the Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

class ApiAuthenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->header('content-type') != 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('The request must be: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

From `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    //\App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthenticate::class,
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'api' => \App\Http\Middleware\ApiAuthenticate::class,
];
```

Comment: Please post the middleware code.

Comment: Post the code from your kernel.php file. You may have missed a comma in your $routeMiddleware array or something simple like that as this should work if you say ApiAuthenticate works with the global middleware

Comment: I've added the `ApiAuthenticate` Middleware code, as well as the arrays from the `Kernel.php`. You can see where I've toggled definition from `$middleware` to `$routeMiddleware`.

Another thing that is very strange: within `routes.php` if I comment out all routes within the group, except for the first one, I get a different error thrown - `NotFoundHttpException`. Very strange.

Comment: As I mentioned above, everything works perfectly as long as I run it using `$middleware` globally, and does not work at all when using `$routeMiddleware`. It appears to me that when using the Route group, the `controller@action` parameters are being ignored/dropped. Which is evident with the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception.

Comment: what URL and method are you calling? Only thing I can think is that global middleware runs first, then the route method is checked, then route/group middleware is run. That may be why. When you add to global, maybe laravel doesn't check if a route actually exists before running your middleware.

Comment: I've tested with all the urls within the Route group, but most of my testing with just the first one `api/users`. Why would the route method fail the check? The specified `UserController@getUsers` is a valid controller/action.

Comment: try modifying your route and see what is returned. If you don't get the same error, your controller is not setup correctly Route::get('api/users', array(function(){return 'hello world';}));

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM! Typo on my end. Dang! But your troubleshooting helped me find it. Thanks.